# How to get the Socket object from Mule TcpConnector

Tags: mule

I want to close the socket once I get an exception during a persistent tcp connection (`SendSocketOpen` is set to true). Currently I believe Mule does not do the clean up for me, it simply releases the socket which means it is returning it to the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, Unless you have `keepSendSocketOpen` (not `SendSocketOpen` as you posted) set to true on the connector or the endpoint, Mule will close the socket when returning it the sockets pool. If you forcefully close the socket, Mule should recover because it validates sockets when it takes one from the pool. So Mule should detect it's been closed and recreate it.

The problem is indeed to get a hold of the socket: AFAICS the only option is to extend `org.mule.transport.tcp.TcpMessageDispatcher` and configure the connector with a `service-overrides` child element that provides a `TcpMessageDispatcherFactory` that builds your own flavour of the dispatcher.

Comment: Thanks David. I just read it now. I got it to work yesterday. I found out that there's a <custom-connector>. So basically I created my own MessageDispatcher, MessageDispatcherFactory, Connector, and Protocol. And yes, the SendSocketOpen is a typographical error, it's supposed to be a keepSendSocketOpen for sync connections.