# How to close Mule TCP socket when exception?

Tags: mule

I am using a `tcp:connector` with the properties `keepalive` and `keepsendSocketopen` set to `true`.

It has to be ESTABLISHED until I have an exception.

I am using `default-exception-strategy` to catch exceptions.

I want to close the socket in my exception flow and connect a new one.

How can I do this ? help me with some example codes and xml configuration references

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229499/how-to-get-the-socket-object-from-mule-tcpconnector) which I asked a few months back. I am not sure how much Mule have evolved now but this worked for me.